# Powershell - Assigning auto-incrementing values to array containing AD OUs

Tags: arrays, powershell, active-directory

I have a block of code that I've been banging my head over for a few days. I'm trying to grab a list of charter schools and their campuses based on our AD OU structure. I go through and grab the charter name, and then with the charter OU I cycle through and grab the list of campuses. I want to have them in an array that has an auto-incrementing value ($i) because when I grab this data, I want to display it in a menu where the user can select the campus by inputting a number. Essentially each campus has it's own number.

The problem is that when its done doing it's looping, the only values that are returned are those of the LAST charter that it loops through, none of the others proceeding it. The other odd thing is that the key in the array is incrementing just fine, I just cant see them all!

```
# Get list of Charters in AD
$charters = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -LDAPFilter '(name=*)' -SearchBase 'OU=Campuses,DC=INTELLATEK,DC=LOCAL' -SearchScope OneLevel | Select-Object Name, DistinguishedName | Where-Object {$_.name -ne 'All Campus'} 

$i = 1
ForEach ($charter in $charters) {

    # Get list of list of campuses for that charter
    $campuses = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -LDAPFilter '(name=*)' -SearchBase $charter.DistinguishedName -SearchScope OneLevel | Select-Object Name, DistinguishedName, ObjectGUID

    $sel = @{}

    ForEach ($campus in $campuses) {

        # $i 
        # $campus.Name

        $sel[$i]                        = @{}
        $sel[$i]["charter"]             = $charter
        $sel[$i]["campus"]              = $campus.Name
        $sel[$i]["distinguishedname"]   = $campus.DistinguishedName
        $sel[$i]["objectguid"]          = $campus.ObjectGUID

        $i++
    }
}

$sel
```

$sel is outputting as:

[image]

Why would it only be displaying 11-16 (which is the last charter that it loops through)???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only getting the last one because you're re-initializing $sel inside your foreach Charter loop, so every time it goes through a new Charter, all the previous information saved in $sel is wipe out.  You need to get that outside of the loop:

```
i = 1
$sel = @{}
ForEach ($charter in $charters) {

    # Get list of list of campuses for that charter
    $campuses = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -LDAPFilter '(name=*)' -SearchBase $charter.DistinguishedName -SearchScope OneLevel | Select-Object Name, DistinguishedName, ObjectGUID

    ForEach ($campus in $campuses) {

        # $i 
        # $campus.Name

        $sel[$i]                        = @{}
        $sel[$i]["charter"]             = $charter
        $sel[$i]["campus"]              = $campus.Name
        $sel[$i]["distinguishedname"]   = $campus.DistinguishedName
        $sel[$i]["objectguid"]          = $campus.ObjectGUID

        $i++
    }
}

$sel
```

Comment: Oh wow... That's embarrassing. I knew it was something simple that I was just overlooking. Thanks for your response!

Comment: No problem.  Been there, and done that so I recognized all the symptoms.